# How to allow file & folder perminsion in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, file-permissions, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed latest Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS in my laptop to learn Ubuntu OS. Now I am trying to create files and folders inside `/var/www/html` directory but getting permission issue.

[image]

Can you please guide me which commands, I have to run to create files & folders.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites  http://askubuntu.com OR  http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To get permissions, you'll have to prepend `sudo` to your command e.g. `sudo mkdir /var/www/html/mywebsite`. The first command you run with `sudo` will require your password.

Comment: I am not able create any files & folder inside HTML folder. Please check this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8YRx.png

Comment: Open up a terminal and input `sudo mkdir /var/www/html/<your folder name>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need root privileges.

Open terminal using Ctrl+alt+T

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/new_folder
```

This will crate a folder named **new_folder** in html folder

next type,

```
sudo touch /var/www/html/new_file
```

This will create file named **new_file** in html folder